# Error when downloading CoreML file from IBM Watson

Tags: flutter, curl, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson

I want to get the CoreML File in order to integrate it with my project. I am using curl and following the API documentation from IBM Cloud linked below.

```
https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/visual-recognition/visual-recognition-v3#authentication
```

I enter the following command:

```
curl -u "apikey:NRDjngCby2d-pSHOPyWQJxhuB6vOY2uOTCX6KV2BCfwB" --output CompostxLandfillxRecycle_2056123069.mlmodel "https://api.us-south.visual-recognition.watson.cloud.ibm.com/v3/classifiers/CompostxLandfillxRecycle_2056123069/core_ml_model?version=2018-03-19"
```

Returns:

```
 % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0Warning: Failed to create the file
Warning: CompostxLandfillxRecycle_2056123069.mlmodel: Permission denied
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
curl: (23) Failed writing body (0 != 15755)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could it be that the location where you are running the command is a write protected directory or that existing file is protected?

`cd` to your home directory, and then try the curl command again.

Comment: Just tried it and it works. Thanks. Where can I find this CoreML file and how can I use it in an app?

Comment: Great. The file should be in the directory where you ran the curl command. For info about CoreML and Watson Visual Recognition, take a look at the links in the release notes: https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/visual-recognition?topic=visual-recognition-release-notes#20march2018

Can you accept my answer if it solved your issue? Thanks (https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Comment: Sure. Thanks again. I will try it out and let you know.